# Como fazer Tabs Bootstrap dinamico com laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Boa Noite

Estou tentando fazer com que cada Tabs apresente um dado especifico referente ao nome de uma pessoa que no meu trabalho seria nome de um professor

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela **diarios**

```
id - nomedoprofessor - aluno   - diadaaula  - resumodaaula
01 - Adriano         - Carlos  - 2020-01-01 - Fez todas as tarefas
02 - Adriano         - Carlos  - 2020-01-02 - Faltou a aula
03 - Adriano         - Carlos  - 2020-01-03 - Chegou atrasado
04 - Adriano         - Carla   - 2020-01-01 - Teve duvidas mas consegui responder
05 - Adriano         - Carla   - 2020-01-02 - Não quis fazer exercícios, estava cansada
06 - Adriano         - Carla   - 2020-01-03 - Foi embora mais cedo
07 - Adriano         - Antônio - 2020-01-01 - Fez todas as tarefas
08 - Adriano         - Antônio - 2020-01-02 - Fez todas as tarefas
09 - Adriano         - Antônio - 2020-01-03 - Faltou por doença
```

No meu controller eu tenho seguinte códigos

```
public function show($professor){
    $alunos = DB::table('diarios')       
    ->where('nomedoprofessor','=', $professor)         
    ->orderBy('aluno')
    ->groupBy('aluno')
    ->get();
```

Para filtrar por professor

na minha views **professor.blade.php**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
@foreach ($alunos as $aluno)                     
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home-{{$aluno->id}}" role="tab" aria-controls="home-{{$aluno->id}}" aria-selected="true">{{$aluno->aluno}}</a>
  </li> 
 @endforeach
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
 @foreach ($alunos as $aluno)                
   <?php 
      $conteudo = DB::table('diarios')       
       ->where('nomedoprofessor','=', $aluno->nomedoprofessor)
       ->where('aluno','=',$aluno->aluno)         
       ->orderBy('aluno')        
       ->get();        
    ?>
      <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="home-{{$aluno->id}}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-{{$aluno->id}}">
<p>{{$conteudo->diadaaula}} - {{$conteudo->resumodaaula}}</p>
      </div>
      @endforeach
 </div>
```

Mas está aparecendo o erro

**Property [diadaaula], [resumodaaula] does not exist on this collection instance.**

O correto era para aparecer conforme a imagem abaixo, alguém pode me ajudar por favor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma ideia é usar AJAX

Comment: Código na View !!!

Answer (score -1):

O que vou descrever abaixo não responde à sua questão inicialmente, porém eu demonstro um problema de arquitetura em seu código. Quanto às propriedades do erro, provavelmente está usando os nomes dos campos errados.

Não faça o uso de queries na view, resolva isso no modelo ou no controlador, pegue este código:

```
   $conteudo = DB::table('diarios')       
       ->where('nomedoprofessor','=', $aluno->nomedoprofessor)
       ->where('aluno','=',$aluno->aluno)         
       ->orderBy('aluno')        
       ->get();
```

e migre para um método do teu modelo Aluno:

```
// na classe Aluno crie a propriedade
$conteudo = null;


function getConteudo() {
    // isto para garantir que não estará sempre fazendo a consulta
    // no banco, mesmo quando o modelo já está em memória e este
    // método já foi chamado uma vez
    if ($this->conteudo) {
        return $this->conteudo;
    }

    $this->conteudo = DB::table('diarios')       
       ->where('nomedoprofessor','=', $aluno->nomedoprofessor)
       ->where('aluno','=',$aluno->aluno)         
       ->orderBy('aluno')        
       ->get();

    return $this->conteudo;
}
```

Comment: Bom Dia Obrigado mas na verdade tenho fazer um novo foreach antes da div, assim eu resolvi meu problema, obrigado